# I can't pass the object or the datya to another layout data

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have 2 Layout and navmenu XML file I login with username and password and
when I login I get the member name and I have header Layout contains image and textview under it called edit user I need to pass to it the member name I got from the login layout and that is my code

main form

Layout XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout1">

   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout1">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="55px"
        app:titleTextColor="#ffff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:paddingVertical="15dp"
        app:navigationIcon="@mipmap/menu"
        android:background="@drawable/mygradient"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1" />

      <include

          layout="@layout/Include_Main"/>

    </LinearLayout>



      <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView


            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start" 
            app:headerLayout="@layout/headerlayout"
            app:menu="@menu/navmenu"  
            android:id="@+id/navigationView1" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

while the headerlayout form contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:paddingTop="59dp"
    android:background="@color/maindrawer">


    <Refractored.Controls.CircleImageView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/account"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/circleImageView1" />


    <TextView
            android:text="username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/edituser" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:background="@color/maindrawer"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I need to pass the username from the login click to it

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(headerlayout));
        intent.PutExtra("MyData", "Emad Younan Amien");
        StartActivity(intent);
```

Please Help me to change the username text to emad younan

and the code iam using at headerlayout

```
    username = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.edituser);

     string  usee = Intent.GetStringExtra("MyData") ?? "Data is not available";

     username.Text = usee;
    // Create your application here

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Main_Home));
    intent.PutExtra("MyData", "Emad Younan Amien");
    StartActivity(intent);
```

[this image for what I mean with change the name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1Z8q.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
    string usee = Intent.GetStringExtra("MyData") ?? "Data is not available";


    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.navigationView1);
    View headerView = navigationView.GetHeaderView(0);
    TextView navUsername = (TextView)headerView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.edituser);
    navUsername.Text = usee;
```

Comment: Well i don't know how to do it?